# ODataController, if the model is incorrect, it gets null on post

Tags: c#, .net-core, http-post, odata

If there is any wrong property (For example if I send the payload data, Person_ instead of Person), model **fully** gets as null *(Post([FromBody] Request data))*

```
public class Person
{
   public Guid Id { get; set; }

   public string? Firstname { get; set; }
 
   public string? Lastname { get; set; }
}

public class Request
{
   public Guid Id { get; set; }

   public Guid? Personid { get; set; }

   public virtual Person? Person { get; set; }
}


 
public IActionResult Post([FromBody] Request data)
{
   ...
}

 
curl --location --request POST 'https://localhost:7124/v2/request?$expand=Person($select=Id,Firstname,Lastname)/Request&@odata.context=%27https://localhost:7124/v2/$metadata' \
--header 'Content-Type: application/json' \
--data-raw '{
    "Id": "a436677a-fa4b-465e-8e70-211a1a3de8e9",
    "Personid": "be9b53ad-4dfb-4db5-b269-32669f7c4e2d",
    "Person_" : {
        "Firstname": "JOHN",
        "Lastname": "SMITH",
    } 
}'
```

I need to get the model even though some properties not correct according to model schema.

What could be the reason for it being null?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One of the main issues is that the *type* argument forms a strong contract that the OData subsystem tries to enforce. If the *Deserializer* cannot match the expected type fully, then it returns `null`, not a partially constructed object, or an empty object if none of the properties matched.

> What you are expecting was a lazy implementation that we often took for granted in previous versions of OData and JSON.Net, but the OData Entity Serializer doesn't work this way any more.

When the argument is null, the `ModelState` should provide detailed information on the reason for the failure.

OData has support for allowing additional members, it is called [Open-Type Support](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/web-api/overview/odata-support-in-aspnet-web-api/odata-v4/use-open-types-in-odata-v4). Similar to the *catch all* solutions in other deserialization methods, we designate a dictionary to route all un-mapped properties so that you can inspect them after deserialization. [This was a good walkthrough in .Net FX](https://devblogs.microsoft.com/odata/tutorial-sample-how-to-use-open-type-in-odata/) but basically we add the property:

```
public class Request
{
   public Guid Id { get; set; }
   public Guid? Personid { get; set; }
   public virtual Person? Person { get; set; }
   public IDictionary<string, object> DynamicProperties { get; set; }
}
```

Then in your model builder you need to declare the type as open:

```
builder.Entity<Request>("request").EntityType.IsOpen();
```

This is alone is still going to be hard to use though because your additional member is a complex type, so the type cannot be easily resolved automatically.

You could implement your own deserializer, but that is a lot more universal to all of your controllers and endpoints, you should take a little bit more care because it really opens a back door and cancels out a lot of functionality if you don't do it right. In [your example](https://stackoverflow.com/a/74675157/1690217) the `_person` is omitted entirely, which might not be your intention.

> Other solutions are a bit more permanent and messy, like adding additional properties to your model to capture the input and re-assign it internally. The best advice however is to respond to the client with an adequate error message so that they update the call.

There is another way that we can also cheat by using the `JToken` type, instead of the expected concrete type. This will universally ingest the payload from the request, then we can use good old JSON.Net to resolve the object:

```
/// <summary>
/// Inserts a new item into this collection
/// </summary>
/// <param name="item">The item to insert</param>
/// <returns>CreatedODataResult</returns>
[EnableQuery(AllowedQueryOptions = AllowedQueryOptions.Format | AllowedQueryOptions.Select)]
public virtual async Task<IActionResult> Post([FromBody] Newtonsoft.Json.Linq.JToken x)
//public virtual async Task<IActionResult> Post(TEntity item)
{
    TEntity item = x.ToObject<TEntity>();

    ... insert custom logic to resolve the badly formed properties

    // Tell the client that the request is invalid, if it is still invalid.
    if (!ModelState.IsValid)
        return BadRequest(ModelState);

    //EvalSecurityPolicy(item, Operation.Insert);
    await ApplyPost(item);
    //UpdateRelationships(item, Operation.Insert);

    await _db.SaveChangesAsync();

    return Created(item);
}

/// <summary>
/// Inheriting classes can override this method to apply custom fields or other properties from dynamic members in the posted item, base class will apply TenantId only if it has not already been applied
/// </summary>
/// <remarks>This process is called after the usual validation overriding just this process means you do not have to replicate the existing internal logic for the afore mentioned tasks.</remarks>
/// <param name="item">The new item that has been uploaded</param>
/// <returns>Promise to add the item to the underlying table store</returns>
public virtual Task ApplyPost(TEntity item)
{
    GetEntitySet().Add(item);
    return Task.CompletedTask;
}
```

*This is a base class implementation of `ODataController` Inheriting controller classes only override `ApplyPost` if needed. I've commented out some more advanced logic routines to give you other hints on how you might use this pattern.*

Is a good practice? I'm undecided but it works and will allow your API to be resilient to schema changes that the client hasn't yet been updated to support,  you can also inspect and handle the invalid `ModelState` in your controller before you return to the caller, or can easily add your own custom mapping logic if needed.

Answer (score 0):

The problem is the declaration of `Person`  in the class `Request`, It should be `public Person Person_ { get; set; }`.

You can declare it as `public virtual Person? Person_ { get; set; }` also if you don't want to change the declaration.

The only catch here is the suffix underscore before `Person`.

If you don't want to change the declaration then you can use `JsonProperty`

```
[JsonProperty("Person_")]
public virtual Person? Person { get; set; }
```

Comment: Thanks your answer, but I have already know model is wrong and my problem is that. When I send a model which has incorrect property name, serializer gives completely null object. I want to get the incoming data even if the model is not valid for the schema.

Answer (score -1):

I have found a solution. I have used a custom `ODataResourceDeserializer` to handle the exception of *doesn't exist properties* and, included a `try`/`catch` block in the `ApplyNestedProperty` method's content. So the web service cannot throw an exception for *not exists properties* while deserialization process.

```
public class CustomResourceDeserializer : ODataResourceDeserializer
{
    public CustomResourceDeserializer(IODataDeserializerProvider deserializerProvider) : base(deserializerProvider)
    {
    }

    public override void ApplyNestedProperty(object resource, ODataNestedResourceInfoWrapper resourceInfoWrapper, IEdmStructuredTypeReference structuredType, ODataDeserializerContext readContext)
    {
        try
        {
            base.ApplyNestedProperty(resource, resourceInfoWrapper, structuredType, readContext);
        }
        catch (System.Exception)
        {
             
        }
        
    }
}
```